# Append string in before the last word Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My input1 is "perfectly clean" "multi action" cleansing
My input2 is "perfectly clean" "multi action"

I need to append "and" in the last but one position 
eg: if input1 then output should be "perfectly clean" "multi action" and cleansing 
if input2 "perfectly clean" and "multi action"

The input is dynamic but I need the output with the double codes as in the input 
can u help me with a solution which satisfies both the input

i tried like this

```
var text = g_eCatalogMeta.searchCorrected,
    clength = text.split('"');

clength = clength.filter(function(n){ return n != "" && n!=" "});

if (clength.length >1) {
   var aa =clength.length;
   clength.insert(aa-1, "und");
   text = clength.join;
}
```

But could not get the double codes and the last word.
Please help me out.

Comment: Why are you splitting on the '"' .. As per my understanding, the split should be on ' '.. and you simply need to concatanate all elements of the split-created array and add ' and ' just before the last element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is a regular expression that inserts `and` before the last quoted string or the last word.

```
str.replace(/("[^"]+"|\w+)$/, "and $1");
```

https://regex101.com/r/yK5tD9/1

Regex breakdown:

```
(       = start of group 1 
"[^"]+" = quote, some non-quotes, quote
|       = OR
\w+     = a word
)       = end of group 1
$       = end of string
```

`$1` in replacement means "whatever group 1 matches".

Comment: Cool application of regex.