# js how to append text to last word in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

Dear all I have string like this

```
var str = "apple banana book pen";// str is up to user input
```

and I need result like this

```
appple banana book and pen
```

This is my code

```
var s = "apple banana book pen";
s =s.replace(/("[^"]+"|\w+)$/," and ");
console.log(s)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Append string in before the last word Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27503893/append-string-in-before-the-last-word-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

If the list is always on the format `"string1 string2 string3"` and you want the output `"string1 string2 and string3"`, this should work:

```js
function addAnd(str) {
  const words = str.split(' ') //turn the string into a list of words
  if (words.length == 2) { //if the string has no spaces, simply return the string ("apple" => "apple")
    return str
  }

  words.splice(words.length - 1, 0, 'and') // insert the word right before the last word

  return words.join(' ')
}

console.log(addAnd("apple banana book pen")) // "apple banana book and pen"
```